# Pages library missing from SP2019 Site contents

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, publishing, pages

I am working with SP2019 and on Site contents of root site collection, I am not seeing Pages library. Both SharePoint server publishing and sharepoint server publishing infrastructure features are enabled, still weird part is pages library still not available under site contents.

Does anyone know the reason? On all the subsites, I see pages library under site contents but missing from top level site contents, sounds weird to me.

Can anyone help please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can troubleshoot as following:

Deactivate and re-activate the publishing feature and check again.

Go to SharePoint Designer to open this top level site->Lists and Libraries, check if you can view the Pages library.

If you can view the Pages library in SharePoint Designer, try to deactivate the publishing feature, delete the Pages library in SharePoint Designer, re-activate the publishing feature, then check if you can view the Pages library.

Besides, here is a similar post to use [PowerShell command](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2011/09/15/common-error-the-site-is-not-valid-the-pages-document-library-is-missing/) to update the value of the __PagesListId property value to match the ID of the Pages library, check if it helps:

```
$web = get-spweb http://site-collection/path-to-affected-site
$correctId = $web.Lists[“Pages”].ID
$web.AllProperties[“__PagesListId”] = $correctId.ToString()
$web.Update()
```

Comment: Will the re-activate of feature impact the subsites?